# Handling table records of dynamically created CTabItem in a CTabFolder - SWT

Tags: java, swt

I am working with an eclipse plugin project, in which there is a `CTabFolder` with a `CTabItem` having a table and add & remove buttons.

New `CTabItem`s are dynamically added to the `TabFolder` at runtime, when the user clicks a button. Each tab item will have the same table and the 2 buttons.

The add/remove buttons in a particular tab item will add/remove record(s) to/from the table of a particular tab item.

Can anyone guide me how to implement this?

Comment: What are you struggling with? You've got all the step lined out in your question. What have you tried so far and how far have you gotten?

Comment: I was able to add new tabs to the TabFolder (with each TabItem having a table and 2 buttons) but struggling while accessing the table of particular tab item added in the TabFolder. And the issue was resolved when I tried to get the TabItem that has focus currently using "tabFolder.getSelection()". Then I was able to access the table available in the accessed TabItem. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the SWT Snippets for CTabFolder?

There are some snippets that show how to add/remove tabs.
https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

Comment: Thanks Leo for sharing this resource.